# In R: package::RWebLogo throws error "....had status 127"

Tags: python, r

I get the following warning when I try to make a logo plot with the `RWebLogo` package. It does not save the logo.pdf file.

```
library(RWebLogo)
weblogo(c('CCAACCCAA', 'CCAACCCTA', 'AAAGCCTGA', 'TGAACCGGA'), 
        file.out="D:/logo.pdf",
        open =F)

Warning message:
running command 'C:/Users/mhra/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RWebLogo/extdata/weblogo-3.3/weblogo < C:\Users\mhra\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpY9RydF/tmp.logo > D:/logo.pdf --format 'pdf' --size 'large' --fineprint ''' had status 127
```

I should say that Im really not into Python (which `RWebLogo` wraps), but it seems as it is NOT the python dependency that goes wrong:

```
library(findpython)
can_find_python_cmd()

[1] TRUE
attr(,"python_cmd")
[1] "D:\\Python34\\python.exe"
```

Any ideas ?